# Logical volume attributes

Tags: lvm, lxc

I've used lxc-clone command to clone my lvm-based container (test_lvm was copied to create u33). Container works fine, but the output of `sudo lvs` confuses me:

```
  LV                             VG         Attr      LSize Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  test_lvm                       containers -wi-a---- 1.00g
  u33                            containers -wi-ao--- 1.00g
```

What is the **o** attribute? Found nothing on the documentation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The meaning of the `o` in the output of `lvs` is described in its [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lvs), under the `lv_attrs` attributes section:

```
          6  device (o)pen
```

Basically this means the device has been mounted.

Comment: https://www.mankier.com/8/lvs has several flags not listed in the current link, like Cahced volumes